# Contacts of Firefox OS problems with mozContacts.tel

Tags: javascript, firefox-os

I've been trying to get the contact name and last name and also get the cellphone number but when I am using the `getAll()` method the Console display this:

```
Found: Daniel Garcia [object Object]
```

As you can see it displays the `Name` + `LastName` + `tel`. Why does it display `tel` like `[object Object]`

Here is my code:

```
var allContacts = navigator.mozContacts.getAll({
    sortBy: "givenName",
    sortOrder: "ascending"
});  

allContacts.onsuccess = function(event) { 
    if (cursor.result) { 
        if (cursor.result.familyName[0]== undefined) {
            cursor.result.familyName[0]= ""; 
        }  
        console.log("Found: " + cursor.result.givenName[0] + " " + cursor.result.familyName[0] + ' ' + cursor.result.tel[0]); 
        cursor.continue();
    } else {
        console.log("No more contacts");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is in the cursor.result.tel object? Can you print JSON.stringify(cursor.result.tel[0]) ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/mozContact.tel , and about the JSON i dont know

Comment: you should just try what Jamesh said. `JSON.stringify(cursor.result.tel[0])` and see what that object looks like. You can also inspect the code in debugger and look at the object

Comment: thank you very much jamesh and Aras it work like you proposed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much it work just like Aras and jamesh proposed

```
console.log("Found: " + cursor.result.givenName[0] + " " + cursor.result.familyName[0]+' '+JSON.stringify(cursor.result.tel[0]));
```

and the console display this:

```
"Found: Daniel Garcia {"type":["mobile"],"value":"8112441018"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

`tel` here is an array of objects - a list of all the possible phone numbers for the contact. Each of this objects has several useful properties. In javascript when you are printing out an object it prints an object string representation (like `[object Object]`).

Check out docs to understand the structure of the `tel` object and get it printed the way you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/mozContact.tel